# How to split a data frame and extract a particular pattern?

Tags: string, r

I have extracted first row of a data frame

```
> top_row 
Date EUR/USD Close USD/JPY Close USD/CHF Close GBP/USD Close EUR/GBP Close EUR/JPY Close EUR/CHF Close GBP/JPY Close GBP/CHF Close
```

The first coulmn is `'Date'`, second column is `'EUR/USD Close'` and so on...
Now, I want to extract EUR, JPY, USD, GBP and CHF i.e. distinct currencies. I tried using`strsplit()` but it doesnt work as it is dataframe.

Please guide me further. Thanks

Comment: so you simply want to parse the header (first row) of the data-frame and extract the single-currency strings 'EUR', 'USD', etc? In other words, this has nothing to do with data-frames right?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Prasad's comment.  This doesn't seem to have anything to do with data.frames.  It seems you just want to extract things from a character vector:

```
curr_pairs <- gsub(" Close","",top_row[-1])
unique_curr <- unique(unlist(strsplit(curr_pairs,"\\/")))
# [1] "EUR" "USD" "JPY" "CHF" "GBP"
```